# Arbitrary index for mysql select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working query that returns the data I need:

```
SELECT 
       round(sum(t.total_talk_time_minutes),2) as TalkTime,
       sum(t.total_outbound) as Outbound,
       sum(t.total_inbound) as Inbound,
       sum(t.dealers_contacted) as Dealers,
       t.date_of_report as Date,
       DAYNAME(date_of_report) as Day
FROM ambition.ambition_totals t
WHERE date_of_report  between
    curdate() - interval 5 day and curdate()
    group by DATE
    order by date
```

However, I'm using it in a php file and need to select and index with it to use for an array index. This is a summation of data and I have no existing data that would exist as an index and would prefer to use an arbitrary number like a row cound or index.

Is there a good way to do this within a php sql call like this?

Comment: How are you fetching this? All you have here is a confusingly big query.

Comment: If the index is arbitrary, why do you need to create it yourself? If you create an array in PHP, it has indexes by definition.